# Django url in a tag doesnt work because it adds new parameters to the url and doesnt remove unnecessary ones

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I googled a lot, but I guess I use the wrong keywords to find the solution:

I have this urls.py file:

```
path('site1', views.site1, name='site1'),     
path('site2/<slug:topic>', views.site2, name='site2'`),
```

I want to add an a-tag to site1. So I would use the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'site1' %}>Link to site1</a>
```

The problem is now that I get an error because the "site1" is added to the end of the current url. So the url looks like this "...site2/site1".

What do I have to change to get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance!

**Update 06. August 2023:**

I believe I understand the issue, but I dont know how to solve it. The content of my second page is stored in a database and pasted in that Django template using a queryset. So the following link is pasted into the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'valuation' %}">Bewertung</a>
```

Therefore the href content on the client side looks like this href="{% url 'valuation' %}" instead of this href="/Bewertung".

But now I don"t know how I can make it work.

**Solution**

I stored the content in a database and had to render the content before passing it to the Django template.

Comment: It smells like a relative URL but url reversion should not produce anything like that. Check if you have anywhere `href="site1"` without `{% url` tag. Or show less obfuscated code and give more real examples of the current url where you are before clicking href and the bad url where you're led to.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for your response!